# Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission only on Xiaomi

Tags: android

I've got this error when updated SDK to 28:
[image]

As you can see It's happen only on Android 8 for Xiaomi devices. Other dependences are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
```

I don't get any user data from device, is it a known Xiaomi bug?

Comment: Could you provide link to your application I could test it? I have also Xiaomi but running custom rom, so that we could define whether it is Xiaomi limitation or hardware. BTW, does your app make any changes to system/ user input? I'm asking because tools like TeamViewer, Vysor, VNC are incompatible with Xiaomi and Huawei devices running stock rom. They allow you to share the screen as read-only -  you can't control device.

Comment: @choletski any luck figuring this one out? I am getting the same crash on Xiaomi devices running Android 8 as well.

Comment: Same here. Looks like Xiaomi messed with system components... AGAIN.

Comment: @Domin I have same problem. You can test my app from installing playstore link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.earn.money.by10sec